# Can a Rigger command multiple drones when jumped into one?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

So a rigger with an RCC and a bunch of slaved drones jumps in to one of his drones. Can this rigger then use the send message/command multiple drones actions while jumped in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you’re jumped into a vehicle or other device, you’re in Virtual
>   Reality mode. (Core 266)

No rule mentions any restriction on Matrix actions as a result of jumping in. Commanding your drones is a Matrix action and you are present in the Matrix. It should pose no difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Shadowrun 5e CRB p267

> Your RCC manages several parallel connections at once, so **you can give a command to one, all, or someof your slaved drones with the same
> Simple Action.** This multi-connection also lets you jump from one
> slaved drone to another without first jumping out of the drone you’re
> leaving.

Pretty straight forward. Note this relies on the pilot program and autosoft of the drone, you are not remote controlling them. Also jumping in is a complex action so you can't jump in + command drone in the same initiative pass. But by RAW it seems you can give a one phrase command as a free action:

Shadowrun 5e CRB p 164

> SPEAK/TEXT/TRANSMIT PHRASE:
>
> One short phrase of verbal communication is a Free Action.

Presumablly a drone's pilot program can understand a simple "shoot back" or "follow" command.

Comment: Jumping in is not necessarily a complex action.